# Translate this simple C code to VBA

Tags: c, vba, excel, output, translate

I am looking to print an output that constitutes a string and a float. 
For example, I calculated the density of a box using D = Mass/Volume. I would now like to generate an output saying "The density of your box is **** kg/cubicM"

This is how that can be achieved in C

```
printf("The density of your box is %d\n", D);
```

How can this be achieved on VBA?

Comment: I can give you the answer. It is very simple but I want to know if you have tried to find it yourself?

Comment: I would recommend readin up on `Msgbox`, `Debug.Print` and `&` (String Concatenation)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `MsgBox` statement with the `Format` function to format the value:

```
MsgBox "The density of your box is " & Format(D, "0.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim boxDensity as String
boxDensity =  "The density of your box is : " & D & "kg/cubicM"
```

The you can use the variable anyway you like